# The fastest way to rotate object Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a big number of objects which I would like to move and rotate in Update() method. The movement part is pretty simple. The issue comes with rotation performance. Operations with euler angles are quite expensive and I want to optimize this part.

I've tried using both

```
transform.rotation.eulerAngles += _rotationDirection * Time.deltaTime;
```

and

```
transform.Rotate(_rotationDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

But they are expensive to call.

Since objects have a constant rotation value, I tried this:

```
private void Awake()
{
    _rotationDelta = Quaternion.Euler(_rotationDirection * _rotationSpeed);
}

private void Update()
{
    transform.rotation *= _rotationDelta;
}
```

This seems to be more performant but my issue now is that I don't know how to link Time.deltaTime to this because you can't just write

```
transform.rotation *= _rotationDelta * Time.deltaTime;
```

So, my question is, **what is the fastest way to rotate an object if the rotation delta is constant during object's lifetime?**

Answer (score -1):

**There are two big issues:**

> One call per frame (Update Method)

> Unoptimized Arithmetic (Transform.rotate)

**Use *RigidBody* instead!**

**Explanation:**
The way Transform.Rotate works is that it calculates rotation and returns rotation as Quaternion which can be then assigned to the rotation value.
Calls in Update method are a big performance issue as they're called before each frame is dropped, and can cause stutters or constantly low fps.

The fix for all of this is simply, RigidBody.
You should set drag and angular drag to 0, so that the rotation doesn't slow down.
You can also freeze position if you will not be moving your objects.

The call will simply be once in the start of the game (in Start() method):

```
int angularPower = 5;

void Start(){
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(angularPower, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't RigidBody eat almost the same amount of performance (comparing to changing transform directly) due to physics calculations?

Comment: Yes that's true. But we've locked position which might eliminate the overhead by skipping movement calculation. The calls to the Transform method will eat performance too. Meanwhile there is one single call to RigidBody in the start.  
And the RigidBody system is designed by Unity Team themselves, which will be a lot efficient.